# How to change the color of all the text in a column?

Tags: tables

Is it possible, in the following simple table, to change the color of all the text in a specific column?

```
\documentclass{article}
\begin{document}
\begin{tabular}{ll}
one & two \\
three & four \\
five & six\\
seven & eight \\
nine & ten
\end{tabular}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Maybe you mean something like this:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{array}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\begin{document}
\begin{tabular}{>{\color{red}}ll}
one & two \\
three & four \\
five & six\\
seven & eight \\
nine & ten
\end{tabular}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: I confirm it works with `longtable` too